Django смена фото в профиле пользователя
Есть модель профиля пользователя, в которой находится поле пользовательской аватарки. Для этой модели есть форма и вьюшка, с помощью которой эту форму можно редактировать. Когда у пользователя уже загружена фотография и он заходит на страницу редактирования профиля, поле загрузки аватарки выглядит не очень красиво:

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то убрать данные надписи, оставив только кнопку повторной загрузки аватара?
models.py:
class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patron = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, blank=True, default='', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='avatars/', default='avatars/default_profile.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patron

forms.py:
class New_user_profile_form(forms.ModelForm):
    patron = forms.CharField(label='Отчество', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Введите отчество...'}), required=False)
    job = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label='-------', queryset=Jobs.objects.all())
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Телефон', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Введите телефон...'}), required=False)
    picture = forms.ImageField(label='Аватар', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('patron', 'job', 'phone', 'picture')

views.py:
def user_update(request, pk):

    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=pk)
    user_form = User_edit_form(instance=user)
    profile_form = New_user_profile_form(instance=profile)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = User_edit_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        profile_form = New_user_profile_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()
                return redirect('users')
        else:
            user_form = New_user_form()
            profile_form = New_user_profile_form()
        return render(request, 'main/user_edit.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/user_edit.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})


user_edit.html:
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="user_info">
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                ...
                
                <div class="user_picture">
                    <h3 class="header">Аватар</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="rows">
                    <p>Аватар пользователя: {{ profile_form.picture }}</p>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


